# filling a matrix by element in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

```
nahead <- 2000
nsim <- 100
w_eq <- 1/2
```

sigma_1 and sigma_2 are matrices of size (nahead, nsim)
nu_ is a vector of size nsim

```
F_equal = function(y, sigma_1, sigma_2, nu_2, size = nahead, sim = nsim){
  y <- as.vector(y)
  len <- sim*size
  final <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(y), ncol = len)
  for (i in size) {
    for (j in sim) {
      final[,???] <- w_eq * (
        dnorm(x = y, mean = 0, sd = sigma_1[i, j]) + 
        dstd(x = y, mean = 0, sd = sigma_2[i, j], nu = nu_2[j]) +
        )
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to properly put the reference of the matrix "final" to have it be of size (length(y), size*sim)

Comment: Try `size*(i - 1) + j`.

Comment: Hello @RuiBarradas. This doesn't work. Here is the error I get : Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , size * (i - 1) + j, value = w_eq * (dnorm(x = y,  : subscript out of bounds.